# how to perform spline interpolation on GPS coordinations?

Tags: numerical-methods, approximation, data-analysis, spline, python

this may look like a programming problem but actually it have to do with math more than programming.

I have GPS coordinations in a csv file that I predict it using a regression model, just two columns with longitudes and latitudes that represent a race track. Now I want to plot it on Google maps to see how it looks like.

When I do that, I noticed that the curve is not smooth which make sense since I predicted those value with my regression model and they are not taking directly from a GPS.

I made a search on how to solve this problem and I find out that usually a spline interpolation is used for this, but I have no idea how to use it. All the examples that I found in the internet assume that we have the x which are the data and y which is the function, in my case there is no function, I just give the data to the model and it predict those values that's it. so if I have longitudes and latitudes, is it possible to make some sort of interpolation so that the curve would look smooth if I plot it?

Example:

let's say those are my data

```
latitudes = array([58.846563, 58.846573, 58.846586, 58.846601, 58.846618, 58.846637,
                   58.846658, 58.846681, 58.846705, 58.846731])

longitudes = array([9.903741, 9.903733, 9.903724, 9.903713, 9.9037  , 9.903686,
                    9.90367 , 9.903652, 9.903633, 9.903612])
```

and when I plot this data it give me some sort of a plot where each point is connected to the other point with a straight line but what I want is to smooth it up. Is this possible to do only if I have longitudes and latitudes as variables and nothing more? I'd appreciate any help

Edit:

I'm sorry that I can't upload my plot for confidential purposes but here is a plot Example, the blue one is how it should be(how I want it to be) and the black one is my result for now which I want to smooth it to be like the blue one

[image]

Comment: It would be helpful to include your plot.

Comment: @AdrianKeister I'm sorry but I can't do that due to confidential reasons. I added a plot to show you what I exactly want, you can imagine that the sin function is the road and the points are my coordinates

Comment: Ok, that's helpful. Do you have a shape in mind that you think the data should fit?

Comment: @AdrianKeister I don't have a specific shape in my mind, the data is also random so it's not like I drove in circles or straight a way. I drove randomly and took the data while driving. I also don't think that the shape will matter. I find a question here it is helpful if you want to take a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31543775/how-to-perform-cubic-spline-interpolation-in-python

Comment: @AdrianKeister I want to do what he did using that spline interpolation or any other interpolation. the difference is in that question he had the x and y and they are 1 D arrays but in my case I have only the x obviously and it's a 2D array (longs and lats)

Comment: So then the next question I would have is this: do you need your spline interpolation to go through every point, or do you not need that, and you'd prefer your interpolation to smooth the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102992/discussion-between-basilisk-and-adrian-keister).

Answer (score 1):

To better see the numbers I am playing with (I am almoast blind), I started muliplying all of them by $10^6$ and took the differences with respect to the first point. This does not change anything to the problem.

This means that the data I worked with are
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 x & y \\
 0 & 0 \\
 10 & -8 \\
 23 & -17 \\
 38 & -28 \\
 55 & -41 \\
 74 & -55 \\
 95 & -71 \\
 118 & -89 \\
 142 & -108 \\
 168 & -129
\end{array}
\right)$$

The parameter used for the cubic splines is the cumulated distance from the origin (in my former research group, we selected on purpose this parameter for applications similar to your - interpolation along $S$-shape curves).

Here are the results of the interpolations (to which you would add the base points given above).
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0.00000 &   0.00000 \\
 3.30174 & -2.73105 \\
 6.64637 & -5.42804 \\
 10.0768 & -8.05692 \\
 13.6189 & -10.5972 \\
 17.2354 & -13.0787 \\
 20.8739 & -15.5435 \\
 24.4830 & -18.0327 \\
 28.0375 & -20.5663 \\
 31.5460 & -23.1371 \\
 35.0188 & -25.7367 \\
 38.4665 & -28.3561 \\
 41.8991 & -30.9873 \\
 45.3254 & -33.6232 \\
 48.7544 & -36.2570 \\
 52.1947 & -38.8818 \\
 55.6550 & -41.4909 \\
 59.1393 & -44.0812 \\
 62.6405 & -46.6582 \\
 66.1500 & -49.2287 \\
 69.6592 & -51.7996 \\
 73.1595 & -54.3775 \\
 76.6430 & -56.9685 \\
 80.1086 & -59.5737 \\
 83.5587 & -62.1911 \\
 86.9954 & -64.8189 \\
 90.4209 & -67.4553 \\
 93.8377 & -70.0984 \\
 97.2479 & -72.7466 \\
 100.653 & -75.3987 \\
 104.053 & -78.0544 \\
 107.449 & -80.7130 \\
 110.842 & -83.3740 \\
 114.232 & -86.0371 \\
 117.621 & -88.7016 \\
 121.008 & -91.3672 \\
 124.393 & -94.0342 \\
 127.775 & -96.7032 \\
 131.154 & -99.3748 \\
 134.529 & -102.049 \\
 137.899 & -104.728 \\
 141.263 & -107.411 \\
 144.620 & -110.098 \\
 147.971 & -112.790 \\
 151.317 & -115.486 \\
 154.659 & -118.185 \\
 157.997 & -120.886 \\
 161.333 & -123.590 \\
 164.667 & -126.295 \\
 168.000 & -129.000
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, we could generate as many points as desired.

I must underline that, even if unnecessary, our producure iterates on the distances (these are updated from the previous splines).